# finding the lowest element of an array

Tags: c++, arrays, variables, element

So I'm trying to find the element that has the lowest value using the if and else if loops.

I have this exact thing typed out for finding the highest value.

Like I literally copied and pasted the same code, and I just changed the symbol.

That one functions perfectly.

But for finding the lowest value in this code, it just comes back as month1 = 0 and the value as 0.

I've seriously scanned line for line to see if there was something off.

But I can't really figure out what is going wrong, and it's slightly frustrating.

Please help.

The variable lowest is a double.

The variable month1 is an integer.

```
    if(rainfall[0] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[0] < rainfall[2] & rainfall[0] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[0] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[0] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[0] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[0] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[0] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[0] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[0] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[0] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[0];
           month1 = 1;
       }
    else if(rainfall[1] < rainfall[0] & rainfall[1] < rainfall[2] & rainfall[1] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[1] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[1] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[1] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[1] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[1] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[1] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[1] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[1] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[1];
           month1 = 2;
       }
    else if(rainfall[2] < rainfall[0] & rainfall[2] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[2] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[2] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[2] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[2] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[2] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[2] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[2] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[2] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[2] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[2];
           month1 = 3;
       }
    else if(rainfall[3] < rainfall[0] & rainfall[3] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[3] < rainfall[2]
       & rainfall[3] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[3] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[3] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[3] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[3] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[3] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[3] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[3] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[3];
           month1 = 4;
       }
    else if(rainfall[4] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[4] < rainfall[2] & rainfall[4] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[4] < rainfall[0] & rainfall[4] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[4] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[4] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[4] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[4] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[4] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[4] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[4];
           month1 = 5;
       }
    else if(rainfall[5] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[5] < rainfall[2] & rainfall[5] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[5] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[5] < rainfall[0] & rainfall[5] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[5] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[5] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[5] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[5] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[5] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[5];
           month1 = 6;
       }
    else if(rainfall[6] < rainfall[0] & rainfall[6] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[6] < rainfall[2]
       & rainfall[6] < rainfall[3] & rainfall[6] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[6] < rainfall[5]
       & rainfall[6] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[6] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[6] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[6] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[6] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[6];
           month1 = 7;
       }
    else if(rainfall[7] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[7] < rainfall[2] & rainfall[7] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[7] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[7] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[7] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[7] < rainfall[0] & rainfall[7] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[7] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[7] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[7] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[7];
           month1 = 8;
       }
    else if(rainfall[8] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[8] < rainfall[2] & rainfall[8] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[8] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[8] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[8] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[8] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[8] < rainfall[0] & rainfall[8] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[8] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[8] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[8];
           month1 = 9;
       }
    else if(rainfall[9] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[9] < rainfall[2] & rainfall[9] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[9] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[9] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[9] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[9] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[9] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[9] < rainfall[0]
       & rainfall[9] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[9] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[9];
           month1 = 10;
       }
    else if(rainfall[10] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[10] < rainfall[2] & rainfall[10] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[10] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[10] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[10] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[10] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[10] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[10] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[10] < rainfall[0] & rainfall[10] < rainfall[11])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[10];
           month1 = 11;
       }
    else if(rainfall[11] < rainfall[1] & rainfall[11] < rainfall[2] & rainfall[11] < rainfall[3]
       & rainfall[11] < rainfall[4] & rainfall[11] < rainfall[5] & rainfall[11] < rainfall[6]
       & rainfall[11] < rainfall[7] & rainfall[11] < rainfall[8] & rainfall[11] < rainfall[9]
       & rainfall[11] < rainfall[10] & rainfall[11] < rainfall[0])
       {
           lowest = rainfall[11];
           month1 = 12;
       }
```

Comment: For one thing `&` is bitwise AND and `&&` is logical AND. (You want the latter).

Comment: The AND operation is `&&` with two ampersands.  What you are doing is something completely different.

Comment: In the future tag your questions with a language - don't put the language in the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in comments, you are using the `&` BITWISE AND operator where you should be using the `&&` LOGICAL AND operator instead.

But even so, there are no loops in the code you have provided, just a whole bunch of `if`s, which is VERY inefficient, error-prone, and difficult to maintain.  Using *actual* loops would greatly simplify the code and solve your problem, eg:

```cpp
double lowest = rainfall[0];
int month1 = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < 12 ++i) {
    if (rainfall[i] < lowest) {
        lowest = rainfall[i];
        month1 = i + 1;
    }
}
```

And likewise for the highest value:

```cpp
double highest = rainfall[0];
int month1 = 1;
for(int i = 1; i < 12 ++i) {
    if (rainfall[i] > highest) {
        highest = rainfall[i];
        month1 = i + 1;
    }
}
```

That being said, consider using the standard [`std::min_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) and [`std::max_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element) algorithms instead:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

auto iter = std::min_element(rainfall, rainfall + 12);
double lowest = *iter;
int lowest_month1 = std::distance(rainfall, iter) + 1;

iter = std::max_element(rainfall, rainfall + 12);
double highest = *iter;
int highest_month1 = std::distance(rainfall, iter) + 1;
```

Or, the standard [`std::minmax_element()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element) algorithm:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

auto iters = std::minmax_element(rainfall, rainfall + 12);

double lowest = *(iters.first);
double highest = *(iters.second);

int lowest_month1 = std::distance(rainfall, iters.first) + 1;
int highest_month1 = std::distance(rainfall, iters.second) + 1;
```

Comment: Thanks for the loop help! I'm still iffy with them myself. As for the second half of your comment, it all went right over my head sorry. Haven't learned any of that yet and I wouldn't feel comfortable using it if I don't actually know what it does.